# Javascript Slideshow Issue. Getting Blank Screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following code to place a javascript slideshow on my website - http://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/. I am trying to implement example 2 given on the link. I must be doing something wrong because all I get is blank screen. No images and the caption.

This is the code that I have on my website.

```
    <div class="bss-slides num2" tabindex="2">
           <figure>
              <img src="bodhgaya.jpg" width="100%" /><figcaption>"Snowying" by <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/fiddleoak/8511209344/">fiddleoak</a>.</figcaption> 
           </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="chardham.jpg" width="100%" /><figcaption>"Starlight" by <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/chaoticmind75/10738494123/in/set-72157626146319517">ChaoticMind75</a>.</figcaption> 
           </figure>
           <figure>
              <img src="taj.jpg" width="100%" /><figcaption>"Snowstorm" by <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/tylerbeaulawrence/8539457508/">Beaulawrence</a>.</figcaption> 
           </figure>
            <figure>
              <img src="konarksuntemple.jpg" width="100%" /><figcaption>"Misty winter afternoon" by <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/22746515@N02/5277611659/">Bert Kaufmann</a>.</figcaption> 
           </figure>
            <figure>
              <img src="http://themarklee.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/good-morning.jpg" width="100%" /><figcaption>"Good Morning!" by <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/frank_wuestefeld/4306107546/">Frank Wuestefeld</a>.</figcaption> 
           </figure>
        </div>
<script src="hammer.min.js"></script><!-- for swipe support on touch interfaces -->
<script src="better-simple-slideshow.min.js"></script>
<script>
var opts = {
    auto : {
        speed : 3500, 
        pauseOnHover : true
    },
    fullScreen : false, 
    swipe : true
};
makeBSS('.num1', opts);
var opts2 = {
    auto : false,
    fullScreen : true,
    swipe : true
};
makeBSS('.num2', opts2);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I clone the repo and check your code.The only difference is the source of the picture.So I put you code on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b07yzh69).

```
I just add the css code
```

Of course you can't see any pictures,but you can see the slide caption.
So did you add the css style in your code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems I have made mistake with the javascript code. Please see if I have got the code in right place. I am not experienced with javascript. This is the test page where I am trying the code. easydestination.net/index3.html